# Mysql result not returned if count 0

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I've got access levels and pages. Pages <=many-to-many=> Levels
I need to count how many opened pages does each level has. But the levels doesn't happen to come out if pageCount is 0.

```
SELECT 
    levels.id,
    levels.name,
    COUNT(pages.id) as pageCount
FROM levels
LEFT JOIN page_levels
    ON levels.id = page_levels.level_id
LEFT JOIN wp_pages
    ON page_levels.page_id = pages.id
WHERE pages.status = 'open'
GROUP BY levels.id
```

Frustrating. Please tell me what am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move condition to ON().

```
SELECT 
    levels.id,
    levels.name,
    COUNT(pages.id) as pageCount
FROM levels
LEFT JOIN page_levels
    ON levels.id = page_levels.level_id
LEFT JOIN wp_pages AS pages
    ON page_levels.page_id = pages.id AND pages.status = 'open'
GROUP BY levels.id
```